# Color picker for temperature/intensity adjustable light

Tags: interaction-design, color, light

I'm designing a color picker for intensity and color temperature on a lamp, where the user can adjust the intensity on the vertical axis and the color temperature on the horizontal axis.

Is this a good design pattern? What would be the better way of displaying this kind of control?

Comment: Would that be a screen UI or a physical picker?

Comment: @ZoeK: Will be a screen UI. I'll use with touch and non-touch screens. However, the interaction will be the same.

Comment: I'll submit a version in couple hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The temperature doesn't have to go from blue to pink, obviously, I have used exemplary hues, just replace them with your system hues.

[image]

Comment: Very precise, I like the visual aspect of this color picker. +1

Comment: +25: Really great! The only thing I can see is that the color scheme is artificial, however, I'll adapt it with http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/

Comment: Glad you like it :-) Wow, I like vendian.org, nice resource, thx for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use *two controls*. The separation of brightness/intensity and warmth/color might be how your user's conceptually break down these options in their head.

[image: Color picker dual scollies]

Comment: +1: Good answer, really, this was my first thought. However, I think that the 2d color picker approach would be great and reduce the setup time for each color change. If I don't get a more satisfactory answer, I'll accept yours.